# can second save transaction t2 be rolled back

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am confused about save transaction in the below scenario :

```
            begin transaction
            save transaction t1
            delete from #t1

            save transaction t2
            begin try
                delete from #t2
                select 1/0
            end try
            begin catch
                rollback transaction t1
            end catch

            begin try
                delete #t3
                select 1/0
            end try
            begin catch
                rollback transaction t2
            end catch
```

If there is error after delete #t2 , transaction t1 is rolled back. But i am not able to understand why i am getting error in the statement 'rollback transaction t2' . I am getting error as 'Cannot roll back t2. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.'. but save point t2 is mentioned in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save transaction is like a checkpoint which says, up to this point your changes will be known as given checkpoint name i..e T1, T2.

If you rollback changes until T2, your changes including checkpoints created after T2 will no longer exists(due to rollback). However your T1 checkpoint is still valid as it was created before T2.

Instead if you revert your changes until checkpoint T1- your checkpoint T2 also got rolled back and whenever you try to rollback your transaction until T2 - SQL throws an error as this transaction checkpoint doesn't exist.

```
drop table #tmp 
create table #tmp (value int)
insert into #tmp values (1)
select * from #tmp

begin tran t1
    insert into #tmp values (2)
    select *, 'begin tran t1' from #tmp

    save transaction t2

    insert into #tmp values (3)
    select *, 'save transaction t2, value {1,2} were aded before t2' from #tmp

    if exists(select * from #tmp where value = 3)
    begin
        select *, 'rolling back until t2, value 3 will be removed' from #tmp
        rollback tran t2--if transaction name is not specfied, complet transaction will be rolled back.
    end

    select *, 'value 3 no more exists' from #tmp
    save transaction t3

    insert into #tmp values (4)
    select *, 'save transaction t3, value 4 will be commited' from #tmp


commit tran
    select *, 'you should be able to see 1, 2, 4' from #tmp
```